# Java Apache HTTP client: initialize persistent file cache

Tags: java, http, caching, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to configure persistent HTTP caching using the `org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.CachingHttpClients` builder. However, when I configure a cache directory, the cache never seems to be read back from disk.

I tried to setup persistent caching using `setCacheDir`, i.e.,

```java
CachingHttpClients.custom()
  .setCacheDir(cacheDir)
  .setDeleteCache(false)
  .build();
```

(see below for a complete example)

The behaviour I'm seeing:

- For each request I see cache entries being written to `cacheDir` of the form `1703170640727.0000000000000001-997b0365.User.-url-path`. So far so good.
- Subsequent requests to the same URL get a cache hit. They are fast. Still good.
- I restart my application.
- Making a request to the same URL again results in a cache miss.

It seems that the cache entries that were written to disk are not being picked up after a restart, and I haven't been able to find a way to do so.

How do I initialize Apache's HTTP cache, so caching persists after restarts?

---

Minimal reproducible example. Running this multiple times results in a "Cache miss" every time, although there are cache entries being written to disk. I would expect reruns to use the cache that was written to disk. Note that I do see a cache hit if I perform two requests to the same URL within the same run.

```java
    File cacheDir = Path.of(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")).resolve("my-http-cache").toFile();
    if (!cacheDir.exists() && !cacheDir.mkdirs()) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Could not create cache directory " + cacheDir + ".");
    }
    try (var client = CachingHttpClients.custom()
      .setCacheDir(cacheDir)
      .setDeleteCache(false)
      .useSystemProperties()
      .build()) {
      HttpCacheContext context = HttpCacheContext.create();
      CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(new HttpGet("https://api.github.com/repos/finos/common-domain-model"), context);

      CacheResponseStatus responseStatus = context.getCacheResponseStatus();
      switch (responseStatus) {
        case CACHE_HIT:
          System.out.println("Cache hit!");
          break;
        case CACHE_MODULE_RESPONSE:
          System.out.println("The response was generated directly by the caching module");
          break;
        case CACHE_MISS:
          System.out.println("Cache miss!");
          break;
        case VALIDATED:
          System.out.println("Cache hit after validation");
          break;
      }
    }
```

Comment: _"It seems that the cache is not being initialized"_ Do you mean the cache is being reinitialized on app restart, and that's not the expected behavior?  Please clarify.

Comment: @JimGarrison That is exactly what I mean yes. I would expect the cache to persist after restarts, otherwise I don't see the point of writing the cache entries to disc.

Comment: I have tried to clarify that in the question.

Comment: There's still a lot of information missing.  You need to, at minimum, show the complete configuration, and tell us what other debugging you've done, such as looking at the cache directory both after shutting down the app, and then after restarting.  Are the cache entries still present in the directory after restart?

Comment: Best of all would be to create a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @JimGarrison Alright, I have extended my code to a standalone minimal example that reproduces the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache's HTTP caching will keep track of a cache entry for each eligible HTTP response. This cache entry points to a certain abstract "resource" object, which holds the cached response. By using `CachingHttpClients.custom().setCacheDir(cacheDir)`, this resource will be a file, i.e., responses will be saved to disk, rather than kept in memory, which saves on memory usage. However, the cache entries themselves are still kept in-memory, so they will not survive a restart.

The following implementation could be used to persist cache entries as well:

```java
/**
 * A variant of {@link org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ManagedHttpCacheStorage}
 * that persists after start-ups.
 */
@Contract(threading = ThreadingBehavior.SAFE)
public class PersistentHttpCacheStorage extends ManagedHttpCacheStorage {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersistentHttpCacheStorage.class);
  private static final String ENTRIES_FILE_NAME = "ENTRIES";

  private Map<String, HttpCacheEntry> entries;
  private final File cacheDir;
  private final File entriesFile;

  public PersistentHttpCacheStorage(CacheConfig config, File cacheDir) {
    super(config);
    this.cacheDir = cacheDir;
    this.entriesFile = new File(cacheDir, ENTRIES_FILE_NAME);

    // A hack to access the entries of the super class.
    try {
      Field f = ManagedHttpCacheStorage.class.getDeclaredField("entries");
      f.setAccessible(true);
      this.entries = (Map<String, HttpCacheEntry>) f.get(this);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  public void initialize() {
    try {
      if (!cacheDir.exists() && !cacheDir.mkdirs()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not create cache directory " + cacheDir + ".");
      }
      if (entriesFile.exists()) {
        try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(entriesFile))) {
          Map<String, HttpCacheEntry> persistentEntries = (Map<String, HttpCacheEntry>) in.readObject();
          this.entries.putAll(persistentEntries);
          LOGGER.debug("Read " + this.entries.size() + " HTTP entries from cache.");
        }
      } else {
        LOGGER.debug("No cached entries exist. Creating a new file at " + entriesFile + ".");
        if (!entriesFile.createNewFile()) {
          throw new RuntimeException("Could not create entries file " + entriesFile + ".");
        }
      }
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  private void writeEntries() throws IOException {
    synchronized (this) {
      try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(entriesFile))) {
        out.writeObject(entries);
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void putEntry(String key, HttpCacheEntry entry) throws IOException {
    super.putEntry(key, entry);
    writeEntries();
  }

  @Override
  public HttpCacheEntry getEntry(String key) throws IOException {
    return super.getEntry(key);
  }

  @Override
  public void removeEntry(String key) throws IOException {
    super.removeEntry(key);
    writeEntries();
  }

  @Override
  public void updateEntry(String key, HttpCacheUpdateCallback callback) throws IOException {
    super.updateEntry(key, callback);
    writeEntries();
  }

  @Override
  public void shutdown() {
    super.shutdown();
    if (!entriesFile.delete()) {
      LOGGER.error("Could not delete entries file " + entriesFile + ".");
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
    CacheConfig cacheConfig = CacheConfig.DEFAULT;
    File cacheDir = Path.of(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")).resolve("my-http-cache").toFile();
    if (!cacheDir.exists() && !cacheDir.mkdirs()) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Could not create cache directory " + cacheDir + ".");
    }
    PersistentHttpCacheStorage storage = new PersistentHttpCacheStorage(cacheConfig, cacheDir);
    storage.initialize(); // Necessary for loading the persisted cache entries
    CloseableHttpClient client = CachingHttpClients.custom()
      .setCacheConfig(cacheConfig)
      .setHttpCacheStorage(storage)
      .setCacheDir(cacheDir)
      .setDeleteCache(false)
      .useSystemProperties()
      .build();
```